# Why am I seeing a compilation error about -falign-loops using LLVM?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, clang, core-plot

I have an iOS application that uses Core Plot, and after I upgraded to Xcode 4.5, I'm seeing the following error when building:

```
clang: error: argument unused during compilation:
'-falign-loops=16' Command
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/u‌​sr/bin/clang
failed with exit code 1
```

What can cause this and how can I fix it?

Comment: You don't have any more information?

Comment: clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-falign-loops=16'Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: Is this with the latest Core Plot code from the repository, or the older 1.0 snapshot? The 1.0 snapshot will no longer build properly under Xcode 4.4+, so you need to update to the latest framework code from the Google Code repository.

Answer (score 2):

`-falign-loops` is a GCC option not used by clang. It is normally a warning in clang, so I assume you have the compiler option set to treat warnings as errors (`-Werror`).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using CorePlot, the following solved the problem

- Go to **CorePlot-CocoaTouch** Project
- **Build Settings**
- Scroll down to **Build Options**
- **Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C** set its value to **LLVM GCC 4.2**

Hope it resolves your issue