# Xcode 4.5 missing library issue with LLVM 4.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, core-plot, objective-c-blocks

I have recently installed xcode 4.5 for iOS 6 SDK, but now when I am trying to run my application onto it, so it is giving me library error. I searched on many topics but cant find solution. I am enclosing my error below

```
clang: error: -Z-reserved-lib-stdc++: 'linker' input unused when '-c' is present
Command /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

My Compiler for C++/C/Objective C  ==  Apple LLVM compiler 4.1, although my source code was working fine with LLVM Compiler 3.1 but now in new xcode 3.1 is not available.

I am facing major issue is static library for coreplot in my project as in 3.1 it is working fine without any errors.

I tried changing path for Header search path, Other linker flag , Library search path, Build Active Architecture to NO in Coreplot static library to create proper ipa but issue didnt resolve. Looking for suggestions.

Comment: Do you have anything in the *additional compiler* or *additional linker* flags?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I seeing a compilation error about -falign-loops using LLVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695060/why-am-i-seeing-a-compilation-error-about-falign-loops-using-llvm)

Comment: I deleted my xcode 4.5 and reinstall 4.3.3 and problem solved, but how to use my source code with xcode 4.5 with LLVM 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending 2 days and then finally downloaded new Core-Plot sdk from https://github.com/djw/core-plot

and it works fine now. I tried all possible solution in modifying my xcode before downloading so kindly download new sdk for fix to above issue.